# Return a ref field based on value of its children's ref

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to return all Product whose Type's ref is veg.

But this is expression seems invalid, what am I doing wrong:

`Products/Product[Type[@ref="veg"]]`

```
 <Products>
            <Product ref="apple">
                <Type ref="fr">FRUIT</Type>
                <Price>100</Price>                
            </Product>
            <Product ref="cabbage">
                <Type ref="veg">VEGETABLE</Type>
                <Price>200</Price>                
            </Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: `Products/Product[Type/@ref="veg"]`

Comment: Actually your expression is valid and should return the result you want.  @JeffMercado's XPath is valid too.